# Export Datagrid Items to a List of Object

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, datagrid

How can I get items listed in a Datagrid and export it in a List of Object?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you specifically want type `object` this should do the trick

```
var list = myDataGrid.Items.OfType<object>();
```

Comment: This is better than to loop with each rows, Thanks.. works like a charm :)